# System.NullReferenceException Object reference not set to an instance of an object (List)

Tags: c#, list, object, properties

```
public List<Faculty> Faculties {get;set;}   
List<Faculty> faculties = FacultiesManager.Faculties;
Faculties.Add(something);
```

how can i interact with the object list

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the list is not initialised. You need to call:

```
Faculties = new List<Faculty>();
```

before you can interact with the list.

Answer (score -1):

It should be

```
public List<Faculty> Faculties = new List<>
```

instead of

```
public List<Faculty> Faculties {get; set;}
```

Comment: Your solution changes it from a property to a field.  Probably not desirable.